# Bounds checked array that shorts out static access

Tags: c++, templates

C++. Imagine I'm putting together a class for statically sized, bounds checked array:

```
template<typename T, int N>
class MyArray
{
    T a[N];
public:
    T & operator[](int i)
    {
         if(i < 0 || i >= N)
             OnError(); //Crash and die horribly
         return a[i];
    }
};
```

Is there a way to avoid performing a bound check at run time if the array access operator is invoked with a compile time constant as an argument?

Comment: Add a `constexpr` overload?  If, C++20, `consteval`

Comment: Turn the function argument into a template parameter?

Comment: "*I'm putting together a class for statically sized, bounds checked array*" - so, you are intentionally reproducing what [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and its [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) method already do?

Comment: @Remy: long story there. `std::array` as it is won't do. The question says "imagine".

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to avoid performing a bound check at run time if the array access operator is invoked with a compile time constant as an argument?

You don't necessarily need to do anything yourself other than enable the optimiser. Compilers are smart, can expand function calls inline and can fold branches that are known at compile time.